# OpenVPN Variables Passed via Script

Tags: linux, iptables, bash, openvpn, tc

Can someone explain and/or direct me to a summary of the variables that are available to be passed to OpenVPN upon a client connection?

For example, what do the following $1, $2, $3, $4 values produce for variables:

```
ip=$1
user=$2
?=$3
?=$4
?=$5
```

etc

To clarify: when a user connects to OpenVPN the following learn-address script is called (please see below)

I would like to know what variables are available to pass to this bash script once a user connects

Here is the learn-address script and the first (2) variables (at the top of the script) $1 and $2 - are there other variables we can capture (eth0 vs dev1, etc)?

```
#!/bin/bash

statedir=/tmp/

function bwlimit-enable() {
    ip=$1
    user=$2

    # Disable if already enabled.
    bwlimit-disable $ip

    # Find unique classid.
    if [ -f $statedir/$ip.classid ]; then
        # Reuse this IP's classid
        classid=`cat $statedir/$ip.classid`
    else
        if [ -f $statedir/last_classid ]; then
            classid=`cat $statedir/last_classid`
            classid=$((classid+1))
        else
            classid=1
        fi
        echo $classid > $statedir/last_classid
    fi

    # Find this user's bandwidth limit
    # downrate: from VPN server to the client
    # uprate: from client to the VPN server
    if [ "$user" == "myuser" ]; then
        downrate=10mbit
        uprate=10mbit
    elif [ "$user" == "anotheruser"]; then
        downrate=2mbit
        uprate=2mbit
    else
        downrate=5mbit
        uprate=5mbit
    fi

    # Limit traffic from VPN server to client
    tc class add dev $dev parent 1: classid 1:$classid htb rate $downrate
    tc filter add dev $dev protocol all parent 1:0 prio 1 u32 match ip dst $ip/32 flowid 1:$classid

    # Limit traffic from client to VPN server
    tc filter add dev $dev parent ffff: protocol all prio 1 u32 match ip src $ip/32 police rate $uprate burst 80k drop flowid :$classid

    # Store classid and dev for further use.
    echo $classid > $statedir/$ip.classid
    echo $dev > $statedir/$ip.dev
}

function bwlimit-disable() {
    ip=$1

    if [ ! -f $statedir/$ip.classid ]; then
        return
    fi
    if [ ! -f $statedir/$ip.dev ]; then
        return
    fi

    classid=`cat $statedir/$ip.classid`
    dev=`cat $statedir/$ip.dev`

    tc filter del dev $dev protocol all parent 1:0 prio 1 u32 match ip dst $ip/32
    tc class del dev $dev classid 1:$classid

    tc filter del dev $dev parent ffff: protocol all prio 1 u32 match ip src $ip/32

    # Remove .dev but keep .classid so it can be reused.
    rm $statedir/$ip.dev
}

# Make sure queueing discipline is enabled.
tc qdisc add dev $dev root handle 1: htb 2>/dev/null || /bin/true
tc qdisc add dev $dev handle ffff: ingress 2>/dev/null || /bin/true

case "$1" in
    add|update)
        bwlimit-enable $2 $3
        ;;
    delete)
        bwlimit-disable $2
        ;;
    *)
        echo "$0: unknown operation [$1]" >&2
        exit 1
        ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Comment: Please provide more context. Where are you seeing these in use?

Comment: In what context?   Is this for passing from OpenVPN values to one of the various hook scripts?  Did you check the environmental variables section of the [man page](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn23ManPage)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> when a user connects to OpenVPN the following learn-address script is called

The $1, $2, and $3 are the arguments passed to the script, that are documented in the man page.

```
--learn-address cmd

...

Three arguments will be appended to any arguments in cmd as follows:

[1] operation -- "add", "update", or "delete" based on whether or not 
    the address is being added to, modified, or deleted from OpenVPN's
    internal routing table. 
[2] address -- The address being learned or unlearned. This can be an IPv4 
    address such as "198.162.10.14", an IPv4 subnet such as "198.162.10.0/24", 
    or an ethernet MAC address (when --dev tap is being used) such 
    as "00:FF:01:02:03:04". 
[3] common name -- The common name on the certificate associated with the 
    client linked to this address. Only present for "add" or "update" 
    operations, not "delete".
```

Comment: Thanks, are there any other arguments available beyond $1, $2 and $3?  Or is it just these (3)?

Comment: Yes, and the are IN THE MAN PAGE.  Under the 'Environmental Variables'.  Seriously, spend some time.  Look at the man page.  You could also dig into the source code if really want to see what is going on.

Comment: Thanks, remember the code of ethics.  I have looked at the Man Page, maybe I should have worded this question better.  When I use $2 I can also capture the name of the Client Certificate, and yet the Man Page lists that $2 captures the address that is being learned or unlearned.  Are there additional variables I can capture?

Comment: If you want to see everything that is **actually** being passed add a line like this at the start of your script.  `(echo "$*" ; export )> /tmp/blah`

Comment: Awesome, I will try this.  I think this is a very relevant question - I was thrown off by $2 capturing the name of the OpenVPN certificate name which was not explained on the Man Page via learn-address, so I was wondering if there are other variables not mentioned in the Man Page that we can capture

Answer (score 0):

The variables you mention have nothing to do with OpenVPN.

Rather, they are bash variables, that refer to command-line arguments that are passed to the script. `$1` refers to the first argument, `$2` to the second, etc.

Comment: Are you sure EEAA?  The second line user=$2 passes the name of the OpenVPN client to the bash script

Comment: Yes I am sure. The script you refer to is a bash script, not anything unique to OpenVPN.

Comment: And your interpretation of `user=$2` is incorrect. That line assigns to the variable "user" whatever value is passed as the second argument to the script.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I am missing something here - where does the second argument that is passed to the script come from?

Comment: It comes from whatever calls the script.

Comment: `have nothing to do with OpenVPN` they aren't environment variables, but they do come from OpenVPN.  That the values will be are pretty clearly documented in the man page.

Comment: @Zoredache Thanks for the clarification - are there any other arguments available beyond $1, $2 and $3? Or is it just these (3)?